# Ionic cordova plugin - Alipay

Tags: ionic3, alipay

my question is so simple: [the Alipay ionic plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/alipay/) is for global or local version.
By local version I mean, the version used only for people they live in China.
Thanks for all they have tried to help me.

Answer (score 0):

I respond to my question in case this could help anyone.

Yes,  the Alipay ionic plugin is for global or local version.
I use it to integrate Alipay payment for mobile application used only inside China.